# Find the order of $f'(x)\approx \frac{1}{12h}[-f(x+2h)+8f(x+h)-8f(x-h)+f(x-2h)]$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, numerical-methods, approximation

> 1. Find the order of approximation of
>      $$f'(x)\approx \frac{1}{12h}[-f(x+2h)+8f(x+h)-8f(x-h)+f(x-2h)]$$
> 2. Use the expression to find approximation for $f''(x)$

1. $$-f(x+2h)=-(f(x)+2hf'(x)+\frac{4h^2}{2}f''(x)+o(h^3)=\\=-f(x)-2hf'(x)-\frac{4h^2}{2}f''(x)-o(h^3)$$

$$f(x-2h)=f(x)-2hf'(x)+\frac{4h^2}{2}f''(x)-o(h^3)$$

$$8f(x+h)=8(f(x)+hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)+o(h^3)=8f(x)+8hf'(x)+8\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)+8o(h^3)$$

$$-8f(x-h)=-8(f(x)-hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)-o(h^3)=-8f(x)+8hf'(x)-8\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)+8o(h^3)$$

So

$$|f'(x)-\frac{1}{12h}[-f(x+2h)+8f(x+h)-8f(x-h)+f(x-2h)]|=\\=|f'(x)-\frac{1}{12h}[-4hf'(x)-2o(h^3)+16hf'(x)+16o(h^3)]|=\\=|f'(x)-f'(x)-\frac{14o(h^3)}{12}|=o(h^3)?$$

2.

We just plug $x+2h,x+h,x-h,x-2h$ to the approximation and get:

$$ f''(x)\approx \frac{[-f(x+4h)-16f(x+3h)+16f(x+h)-130f(x)+64f(x+2h)+64f(x-h)+64f(x-2h)-64f(x-3h)]}{144h^2}$$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $u(h)=f(x+h)-f(x-h)$, then we get the Taylor-MacLaurin expansion
$$
u(h)=2f'(x)h+\frac13f'''(x)h^3+\frac1{60}f^{(5)}(x)h^5+...
$$
Then apply Richardson extrapolation to eliminate the third degree term
\begin{align}
u(2h)-2^3u(h)&=2f'(x)[(2h)-2^3h]+\frac13f'''(x)[(2h)^3-2^3h^3]+\frac1{60}f^{(5)}(x)[(2h)^5-2^3h^5]+...\\
8u(h)-u(2h)&=12f'(x)h-\frac25f^{(5)}(x)h^5+...
\end{align}
so that indeed you get
$$
\frac{-f(x+2h)+8f(x+h)-8f(x-h)+f(x-2h)}{12h}=f'(x)-\frac1{30}f^{(5)}(x)h^4+O(h^6)
$$

---

Now you can do the same with 
$$v(h)=f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)=2f''(x)h^2+\frac1{12}f^{(4)}(x)h^4+\frac{2}{6!}f^{(6)}(x)h^6+...$$

Comment: One must use Richardson extrapolation or my way is correct too?

Comment: The canceling-out of the first, lowest order error term is called Richardson extrapolation. Meaning, I just added the name to the process as keyword for further research. Other than that, I wanted to demonstrate that the symmetric approach reduces the number of terms to consider and thus allows an easier handling of the required higher order terms. Your result of $o(h^2)$ (you wrongly omitted the division by $h$) is not wrong, but it is not complete, as the symmetry gives the even error order $O(h^4)$.